# Tag synonym request: [compiling-from-source] -> [compiling]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

The [compiling-from-source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/compiling-from-source) tag is rarely used and the potential differences between it and [compiling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/compiling) are small and mostly theoretical.

Comment: Yay for theoretical tags! If nobody has any objections, I'll merge them tonight when I get home.

Comment: Motion Seconded/Thirded